# "A reference to a volatile field will not be treated as volatile" implications

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, volatile

The following code

```
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    volatile int counter = 0;
    public void Increment()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    }
}
```

Raises the following compiler warning:

```
"A reference to a volatile field will not be treated as volatile"
```

Am I doing something wrong here to raise this warning? Why does the compiler me warn about this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0420):

> A volatile field should not normally
>   be passed using a ref or out
>   parameter, since it will not be
>   treated as volatile within the scope
>   of the function. There are exceptions
>   to this, such as when calling an
>   interlocked API.

Comment: I'd say that the Interlocked methods still aren't treating it any differently to how they'd treat any other field - it's just that *all* fields are handled in a special way by Interlocked.

Comment: Agreed. Volatile is irrelevant to the Interlocked API. But in certain cases, it's very useful to mix Interlocked and volatile.

Comment: a bit late to the party, but @IamIC : care to elaborate which cases would those be?

Comment: @jajdoo in a nutshell, volatile merely stops compiler and CPU optimizations on values that could prevent threads/cores from seeing the latest value. So it's a mandatory attribute for values that are accessed from multiple threads. However, volatile does not provide atomic operations. For that, we need Interlocked. We could use only Interlocked and not volatile, which is what .Net is looking for. But on x86 that is less efficient for reads, so mixing the two is optimum. On Itanium and ARM, we must always use Interlocked.

Answer (score 35):

Basically the warning is that when you pass a volatile field by reference, the calling code doesn't know to treat it in a volatile manner. For Interlocked.Increment that probably doesn't matter, due to the nature of the method - but then you don't need the variable to be volatile *anyway* if you're using Interlocked.

In general, I think I'd avoid mixing the two - if you're using Interlocked, do it *everywhere* (using `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref counter, 0, 0)` to read it). I can't say I use volatile very often, personally. For simple counters I *might* use Interlocked, but I'm more likely to use a lock for most tasks.

Comment: You are getting me confused. In a previous question (395232) I understood from your answer that I needed both Interlocked and volatile. Now you say "you don't need the variable to be volatile anyway if you're using Interlocked."

Comment: No, they're alternatives to each other: "Or preferably use Interlocked, a volatile variable, or a lock." That was meant to give three *different* approaches, not a combined one. Was that the part which was misleading you?

Comment: I understand that in a multiprocessor enviroment, multiple caches can make one processor increment one cached value that isn't the last value. In that case, as far as I know, a Interlocked won't help, cause it does not creates the MemoryBarrier that is needed to refresh the caches.

Comment: One question, do you visit every question you answered to check if anyone has commented, or you have some sort of RSS that alerts you?

Comment: Interlocked does everything required to make it right - memory barriers, atomicity etc. It would be useless without this.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've found that mixing Interlocked and volatile is useful for things like linked lists, where a CAS is needed for the read move next, but volatile is fine for write create next. Also, I wouldn't position Interlocked and volatile as alternatives since they serve totally different purposes.

Comment: @IanC: I'd say they have *subtly* different purposes - but totally? I think that's a stretch.

Comment: @JonSkeet What I mean is Interlocked is designed to ensure operations are atomic. Volatile is designed to ensure variables aren't cached and are "fresh". Although Interlocked does this too, their purposes are different.

Comment: @IanC: How about Interlocked.Read, Interlocked.MemoryBarrier? I'd also argue that the exact guaranteed behaviour of volatile is sufficiently subtle that it's not appropriate for most developers to use (including myself).

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree that volatile is, well, volatile :). The fact it can't be applied generally to 64 bit variables alone is almost sufficient to disregard it, IMO. I use it exclusively for freshness for 32 bit variables & objects, and understand this applies only to the variables volatile is applied to. It has no other guarantees as far as I'm concerned, such as preventing write/read reordering (cf. Albahari). For that, Interlocked / MemoryBarrier / lock. Interlocked.Read & Thread.VolatileRead also serve to guarantee freshness, as does volatile. I understand what you're saying in this regard.

Answer (score 31):

Use this:

```
#pragma warning disable 420
if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isLoaded, 1, 0) != 0)
    return;
#pragma warning restore 420
```

Comment: But it does come in handy once you understand the other answers, should you decide to use both Interlocked and volatile.

Comment: @JaderDias -- No, but it tells you what to DO about the warning.  Which is super useful. -- Also the artwork was kind of funny too.

Comment: @RyanM the artwork was funny. Why did you remove it? This answer looks naked without it! 

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because you're passing the field by reference. I think what this means is that the target method has no idea the field is marked as `volatile`, and therefore will not treat it as such.