# Compare and exchange as a nonatomic operation

Tags: c#

I got a [book about programming in C#.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735676828) There is an example. Let me copy and paste the context.

...Introduced the usage of *Interlocked*(omitted here).

> You can also use the *CompareExchange* method. This method first checks to see whether the expected value is there; if it is, it replaces it with another value.
>
> Listing 1-41 shows what can go wrong when comparing and exchanging a value in a nonatomic operation.
>
> LISTING 1-41 Compare and exchange as a nonatomic operation

```
class Program
{
    static int value = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if(value==1)
                {
                    // Removing the following line will change the output
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    value = 2;
                }
            });
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            value = 3;
        });
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2); // Displays 2
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

> *Task t1* starts running and sees that *value* is equal to *1*. At the same time, *t2* changes the value to *3* and then *t1* changes it back to *2*. To avoid this, you can use the following *Interlocked* statement:

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, newValue, compareTo);
```

> This makes sure that comparing the value and exchanging it for a new one is an atomic operation. This way, no other thread can change the value between comparing and exchanging it.

The book doesn't provide further details and just ends this section at this point.

My question is how to apply `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, newValue, compareTo);` to the code?

Comment: I don't know where to put it.

Comment: Replace all the code within `t1` to `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, 2, 1);`

Comment: `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, 2, 1)` instead of `t1` presumably.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking here. But as others have said, it sounds like all you need to do is put the `Interlocked` statement in the body of `t1` replacing the current contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I guess they mean to replace the non-atomic block:

```
if(value==1)
{
    // Removing the following line will change the output
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    value = 2;
}
```

With

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, 2, 1);
```

**Edit, what problem does Interlocked.CompareExchange solve?**

The two tasks, t1 and t2 both change `value`, potentially concurrently.

This code sequence here a common anti-pattern in multi threaded code - the [ABA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem):

```
if(someUnsynchronizedCondition)
{
    ... Other random code here
    doSomeActionDependentOnTheCheckedCondition();
}
```

The problem with this is that the condition which was checked for (`if (value==1)`) is not necessarily true any longer at the point where the dependent action is taken (`value = 2;` in your case), because other threads can change the variable in the same time it takes for this thread to move from the `if` check to the dependent action (obviously, the more time the "other random code" takes, like a 2 second sleep, the more the risk). But there is always risk, even if there is no extra code in between (i.e. the original code is still prone to ABA even if `Thread.Sleep` is removed entirely).

In the book's example, the action is to mutate the same variable used in the condition, so hence the convenient way of doing this with `Interlocked.CompareExchange` - for Intel processors, this translates to a single `lock  cmpxchg [reg1], reg2` [atomic instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1581718/314291).

In a more general sense (i.e. where the dependent action isn't just to change the checked variable), you'll need to use other means of synchronization, such as a `lock` or [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), especially if there is a bias toward more readers than writers.

**Re : Final result**

Yes, the code will now always show 3, simply because if the first `Task` t1 executes first, it will change the value to 2 which will be overruled by the second `Task` t2 setting it to 3, but if the second Task runs first (setting to 3), then t1 won't update the value because it is 3, not 1.

Comment: Then it displays 3, is it correct? I tried your code.

Comment: @HuiZhao: Yes, it should display 3 because `t1` started before `t2`.

Comment: Yes, the result will always be 3 - I've explained some more.

Comment: @StuartLC,Thank you. Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

The `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, newValue, compareTo);` basically does this:

```
if(value==compareTo)
{
    value = newValue;
}
```

But in an *atomic*, in other words, non-interruptable fashion. This prevents the problem you have in the example code where you check the value, but then the value changes before you assign it a new value. This can be very important in multithreaded code where you have shared variables.

There are other techniques you might see for this kind of thing. For example, using an object to `lock`:

```
lock(someObject) 
{
    if(value==compareTo)
    {
        value = newValue;
    }
}
```

But this will only work if *every other* attempt to change `value` locks on the same object.

Answer (score 2):

It replaces the separate compare and exchange instructions.  In this block from t1:

```
if(value==1) //Compare
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    value = 2; //Exchange
}
```

Hopefully you will have seen that while t1 is asleep, t2 can cut in and set the value to 3 because your compare and exchange are separate - i.e. not atomic.

If you replace that whole block with:

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, 2, 1);
```

Then the runtime guarantees that the compare and exchange are done together and no other thread can cut in the middle of those operations.

It's not a great example because you also necessarily lose the Thread.sleep which makes it less intuitive to follow IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static int value = 1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref value, 2, 1);
        });
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            value = 3;
        });
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to update the comment. Of course it will display 3 now.

Comment: Fair point. I just copied original code for context and replaced what has to be replaced.