# How do I register and implement event handlers for .Net events within F#?

Tags: f#

How do I register and implement event handlers for .Net events within F#?

I reviewed this [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Events) but it seems a bit verbose.

Example:

```
namespace Core

open Lego.Ev3.Core
open Lego.Ev3.Desktop

type LegoExample() = 
    let _brick = Brick(BluetoothCommunication("COM3"))
    _brick.Changed += OnBrickChanged

    let OnBrickChanged = 
        // some logic goes here...
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx

Comment: You should like this: [Reactive programming with Events](http://tomasp.net/academic/theses/events/events.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F#, events are represented as `IEvent<T>` values which inherit from `IObservable<T>` and so they are just ordinary values - not a special language construct.

You can register a handler using the `Add` method:

```
type LegoExample() = 
    let brick = Brick(BluetoothCommunication("COM3"))
    do brick.Changed.Add(fun e ->
        // some logic goes here...
    )
```

You need the `do` keyword here if you want to register the handler inside the constructor of `LegoExample`.

Alternatively, you can also use various functions from the `Observable` module - those implement basic functionality similar to the one provided by Rx:

```
type LegoExample() = 
    let brick = Brick(BluetoothCommunication("COM3"))
    do brick.Changed
       |> Observable.filter (fun e -> ...)
       |> Observable.add (fun e ->
           // some logic goes here...
       )
```

Comment: It was also recently discussed here that subscribing to events is not thread-safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109354/using-f-event-in-multi-threaded-code