# Events not arriving in F#

Tags: events, f#

I have to post a simplified version of the code because it's quite big otherwise.

I have two threads running the same code in parallel, we can call them A and B.

I have an object which can be summarized as this:

```
let dataProcessor (settings) =
    async {
        let orderEventHandler = Handler<OrderData>(fun _ orderData ->
                do some stuff with orderData
            )

        try
            externalEvent.AddHandler(orderEventHandler)

            // do a bunch of stuff in a loop

        finally
            externalEvent.RemoveHandler(orderEventHandler)
    }
```

and then I start **multiple** instances of this:

```
Async.StartAsTask(dataprocessor settings1)
Async.StartAsTask(dataprocessor settings2)
```

These tasks get routinely created and destroyed.

The issue I am facing is that the first task is getting all the events, but the second one doesn't seem to get them reliably.
I have printed out logs and some events simply do not arrive.

I realize it is a simplified version of the code, so the issue may not be apparent. My question is: am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You are adding handler and removing it. externalEvent may not have a chance to raise an event during that time.
Do you expect to handle events during "// do a bunch of stuff in a loop"?

Comment: @BartekKobyłecki, the loop part is long lived, it can last a few hours. I should have precised that. From what I am reading, it looks like F# events are not thread safe when it comes to adding / removing events.

Comment: I don't know how a delegate list would be less thread-safe in F# than C#, but maybe F# is mutating the delegate list instead of appending to it?  You could try decompiling to C# with SharpLab.io and see what's going on.

Comment: @EricP, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109354/using-a-f-event-and-asynchronous-in-multi-threaded-code that seems to have a similar problem. I haven't had a chance to try their solution yet

Comment: @Thomas that's really interesting.  So if it was a concurrency issue, then sometimes both dataProcessors work, and sometimes only one works?  Does putting a Thread.Sleep between the Async.StartAsTasks change anything?

Comment: I haven't tried the Thread.Sleep, but I would imagine it would fix it because the ConcurrentEvent object (2nd answer from the question above) does fix the problem.