# is it possible to let the lock{} or similar structure lock on writes only?

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

well i mean i have several sections of code that use some variable i want to protect.
but the idea is that several threads only read that variable.
and only one threads is writing to it and it does that not that frequetly.
i want to be able to let multiple threads do reading at the same time and only lock this varialbe when the the writing thread is accessing it.

if i use the normal lock(variable){} construct then all the reading threads will be blocked on each other.
so is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(VS.71).aspx) class.

> ReaderWriterLock is used to synchronize access to a resource. At any given time, it allows either concurrent read access for multiple threads, or write access for a single thread. In a situation where a resource is changed infrequently, a ReaderWriterLock provides better throughput than a simple one-at-a-time lock, such as Monitor.

Comment: `ReaderWriterLock` has multiple issues with it; the newer `ReaderWriterLockSlim` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx is a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is a simple value (an int), you can use `System.Threading.Interlocked`, like this:

```
int counter = 0;
void Worker1()
{        
    if (counter < 5)  // read is safe
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter); // write
        // ...
    }            
}
```

Notes

- `counter` does  [**not** has to be volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186515/interlocked-and-volatile/1186562#1186562).
- if you use long, read with `Interlocked.Read()`
- if your 'variable' is an object, use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` or maybe just stick with `lock() { }`