# How can a cacheline sized struct wrapping a mutable, volatile int64 be created in F#?

Tags: f#

I want to create a  cacheline sized struct wrapping a mutable, volatile int64 in F#. I’ve tried various struct definitions including the one below, but can't get anything to compile.

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 64)>]
type MyStruct1 (initVal:int64) =
    [<VolatileField>]
    let mutable value = initVal
    member x.Value 
        with get () = value
        and set(valIn) = value <- valIn
```

which gives this error: "Structs cannot contain value definitions because the default constructor for structs will not execute these bindings. 
consider adding additional arguments to the primary constructor for the type". I can't see what additional arguements I could add to the primary constructor above.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `struct` definition could be

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 64)>]
type MyStruct =
    [<FieldOffset(0)>]
    val mutable value : int64
    new(initVal:int64) = { value = initVal }
    member x.Value
        with get() = x.value
        and set(valIn) = x.value <- valIn
```

but then, `[<VolatileField>]` is not allowed on val bindings and structs [can't contain let bindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233233.aspx).

TL;DR: AFAIK ***this*** is impossible in F#

As pointed out by @V.B. you could use `Interlocked` which gives a superset of `volatile`s guarantees (stronger guarantees ≈ more overhead). It might then be better to `private`ize `value` to prevent (accidental) writes circumventing the barrier:

```
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 64)>]
type MyStruct =
    [<FieldOffset(0)>]
    val mutable private value : int64
    new(initVal:int64) = { value = initVal }
    member public x.Value
        with get() = Interlocked.Read(&x.value)
        and set(valIn) = Interlocked.Exchange(&x.value, valIn) |> ignore
```

Comment: You could use `Interlocked` methods inside the property

Answer (score 0):

`Interlocked` gives similar guarantees as `volatile`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186515/interlocked-and-volatile).

```
open System.Threading
[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 64)>]
type MyStruct =
    [<FieldOffset(0)>]
    val mutable value : int64
    new(initVal:int64) = { value = initVal }
    member x.Value
        with get() = Interlocked.Read(&(x.value))
        and set(valIn) = Interlocked.Exchange(&(x.value),valIn) |> ignore
```